# About the Heine-Cantor theorem.

Tags: continuity

I don't understand the Heine-Cantor theorem because of one example:
The function $x\to \frac{1}{x}$ is not uniform continuous, and we can clearly see in the graph just by looking at the interval $[1,10]$ for instance. 
The Heine-Cantor theorem doesn't seem to work for $x\to \frac{1}{x}$ but I know that I'm wrong.

Comment: Clearly from the graph...

Comment: i still don't get it, why does the theorem work for x->1/x

Comment: Since the function $x\to\frac1x$ is uniformly continuous on the interval $[1,10],$ it's apparent that you don';t know what "uniformly continuous" means. What is the definition of uniform continuity?

Comment: The teacher had explained it today in the classroom but he didn't show us any graphic example, so i don't think i've really understood the concept.
From what i've understood, if f is uniformly continuous, then if you take an epsilon, there exists an alpha such that, for every x,y, if the distance between x and y is lower than alpha, then the distance between their images is lower than epsilon

Comment: my problem is that i can't identify on which set f is uniformly continuous

Answer (score 2):

$f(x)=1/x$ **is** uniformly continuous on $[1,10]$, so I'm not sure what you clearly see from the graph. The function $f(x)=1/x$ is not uniformly continuous on $(0,1]$, but that is fine since the Heine-Cantor theorem states that a continuous function on a closed and bounded interval is uniformly continuous. But $(0,1]$ is not closed.

Comment: what about sin(e^x)?

Comment: what about it??

Comment: It is not uniform continuous, how can we apply the theorem to it?

Comment: uniformly continuous on which set???

Comment: I've known that theorem most of my life but I never knew it had a name. Since when is it the Heine-Cantor theorem? Did Heine and Cantor prove it?

Comment: @bof http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Cantor_theorem

Comment: I looked at that Wikipedia article before I posted my comment. As far as I can see, it says nothing about the history of the theorem or its name.